# Difference between dates in seconds

Tags: c, time.h

I was wondering if there is any way to get the difference, in seconds, of 2 dates introduced by the user and saved in `int`. For example:

```
int date1d,date1m,date1y,date2m,date2m,date2y;

printf("First date(dd/mm/yyyy):");
scanf("%2d/%2d/%4d", &date1d, &date1m, &date1y);

printf("second date(dd/mm/yyyy):");
scanf("%2d/%2d/%4d", &date2d, &date2m, &date2y);
```

I know that `time.h` has the function `difftime()` that does that, but in onder to use it I need to have 2 time_t structs. Can I get time_t structs with only those 3 ints?

[here's some details about the funtion](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_difftime.htm)

Comment: You can look up `mktime()` and take the difference between the results.  Do you want the difference between 'early date' at 00:00:00 and 'late date' at 23:59:59, or some other interval, or noon on both dates?  The difference could be considerable (172,800 seconds, ±2).  Do you want to track differences in daylight saving time?

Comment: I'm not considering any hours, so both hours of those dates would be 00:00:00

Comment: You need to say that in the question — and what do you want to do about switches between winter and summer time?

Comment: For many reasons, it is usually the best bet to use midday (12:00:00) for the times when working on dates only.  In particular, any adjustments (DST, leap seconds) won't make a difference to the date, because there is 12 hours to both the preceding and the succeeding date, and the adjustments, even combined, are smaller than that. Don't forget to set `.tm_isdst = -1`, to tell your C library to determine whether or not DST is applicable then.